# Plank dropping Chromium shortcut

Tags: 20.04, chromium, budgie, plank

I've been using Plank for a couple of years with Ubuntu Budgie. Overall, I have no problems. However, from time to time, I see that my Chromium shortcut is suddenly missing.

Even when I re-add it, it will be there for a while (a few days to a week) then will suddenly not be there anymore. I shut the machine down nightly so I don't think it is related to restart.

I rarely use Chromium but I do use it about once every two days. However, I have never seen this behavior with other shortcuts on Plank, only with Chromium.

Any ideas what would cause this, or how to fix it?

Comment: Chromium is [now a Snap](https://snapcraft.io/chromium), so this may be an issue. Can you reproduce this with other Snap'ed applications?

Comment: It took a week to get the problem to show itself but, after adding in Gnome Clocks (snap) and VLC (snap), just today, Chromium was the only item that disappeared from Plank. The other two are still there. I wonder if it has anything to do with updating (I'm guessing Chromium updates more frequently than the other two).